# How should I implement SSL?

Tags: java, python, ssl

I have a java client which communicates with python server. Both run within out company intranet. None are exposed to Internet. How I am supposed to ensure that communication happens over SSL?

I have read a lot online and I have come up with following conclusions:

1. I will generate primary key and certificate to be used by clients and server using java [`keytool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html). ([creating keystore, private key, certificate and truststore](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggsxx/index.html),[extracting private key from keystore](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/66865/89945))
2. Using private key and certificate inside my python server using `SSLSocket` class as [explained here](https://carlo-hamalainen.net/2013/01/24/python-ssl-socket-echo-test-with-self-signed-certificate/)
3. Using certificate in truststore inside java client as [explained here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/RetrievingaKeyPairfromaKeyStore.htm)

I have some doubts:

1. Are above steps ok?
2. Above seems to be one way SSL. Should I be doing two way SSL?
3. Should I be creating shared secret key and communicating using it?

I know this is something related to requirements. But I am in doubt as I am doing SSL first time.

Comment: 1. They will probably do what you want them to do. No way to say without you trying it. 2. You should know if you need to authenticate the clients from the server. That's an requirement or not. No way to say. 3. I don't know what you mean by that. Do you want to do another encryption on top? Why?

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificates requires validation via (HTTP/HTTPS), I suggest you enable HTTP/HTTPS for the location IP on the router/firewall to allow the validation to go through the internet.

If that is not possible, then you might have to do some local-server SSL validation. By generating a "SELF SIGNED" certificate and registering it manually in both locations.